# Why is it that when using Noether's Theorem, one can assume that the Lagrangian $L$ remains invariant under small perturbations?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, noethers-theorem

Is this just an extension of the idea that with a small enough perturbation, the Principle of Least Action will still hold, and the system will continue to take the most optimal path?

Answer (score 0):

This is what Noether's theorem requires: transformations that leave the equations of motion invariant. This can be achieved if the action is invariant. Then the transformation is called "**a symmetry**".

For this, the Lagrangian doesn't need to remain invariant. It can change but only up to a total derivative (a 4-divergence). In both cases, either remaining invariant, or changing up to a  4-divergence, the **action remains invariant**.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the notion of 4-divergence? When doing some brief research on the topic, I came across the notion of Ricci calculus, which I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: If under a transformation, $\mathcal{L}\rightarrow \mathcal{L}+\partial_{\mu}j^{\mu}$, it is said that the Lagrangia has been shifted by a total derivative, or more precisely by a 4-divergence. This shift term doesn't affect the action $S\sim \int d^{4}x \mathcal{L}$ because after integration it gives only a surface term.